# How can I modify start screen shortcuts properties?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 7 and previous versions, I could right-click a shortcut in the start menu to access its properties.

For example, I used to set up PowerShell to always run as an Admin and to always start in a given directory.

How can I change these properties on a shortcut that appears on the Windows 8 start screen?

When I right-click the shortcut, there is an *Open File Location* option, which takes me to an actual shortcut. Changing the properties on that shortcut does not seem to affect launching the program from the start screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should work. Are you finding this is the result with ALL shortcuts you try it with, or just one specific one you're trying to set up?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/462912/always-start-visual-studio-as-an-administrator-on-windows-8

Comment: It does work for me. Tested with PowerShell (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools) and Notepad (C:\Users\Louis\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories) shortcuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, my bad... After reading the comments on my question, I tested with Notepad and this seems to work.

So in my case it is only PowerShell that seems to ignore the "Start In" parameter. I thought it might have been my PowerShell profile somehow changing the start directory and I have disabled the whole profile, but no cigar. But I guess this would be a different question then.

So the actual answer to the question is:

> Right-click the shortcut in the Start Menu, choose Open File Location, and change the properties on the shortcut file.